# how to open and view sybase dat file

Tags: database, sybase

is it posible to simply open and view a sybase dat file?

I've been trying to look for a tool but every tool asks for server information, and I just want to open the file.

thanks.

Comment: same problem here, no luck yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's just impossible to view content of Sybase ASE devices offline.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to look at the device file, without going through Sybase (or MS or whatever) ?  Why are the methods provided within Sybase (there are several) not adequate ?  What exactly are you looking for, if you tell us that, maybe someone can help.

Comment: Initially, no licence. We have one now but sybase is extremely slow to extract information... all this just to migrate to another database. Even if the problem was solved I feel it was unnecessary.

Comment: Sybase (and MS to a lesser degree) provides (a) security and (b) ANSI compliance.  So the data contained in the devices are not open to inspection, by design requirement, it is not reasonable to expect that it should be.  This is not MS Access, it is a secure enterprise database.

Comment: There are ways to extract data from any database, and yours is not one of them.  First, you are going about it the wrong way.  Access Sybase device files via Sybase; perform what data extracts etc that you need to migrate via Sybase; you can use its export facility for even more speed (the original owner of the dev files should have done that, no additional licence required).  Second, Sybase is famous for its performance, so you must be doing something wrong.  Post a question re a specific extract or export speed problem.